# nAnt and nAntContrib

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, build-automation, nant

I'm having problems building the nAntContrib library using the instructions provided. When running the build I get the following feedback

```
C:\Code\trunk\tools\nAnt-Contrib>..\nant\nant-0.90\bin\nant.exe -D:nant.dir=C:\c
ode\trunk\tools\nAnt\nant-0.90 -f:NantContrib.build
NAnt 0.90 (Build 0.90.3780.0; release; 5/8/2010)
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

Buildfile: file:///C:/Code/trunk/tools/nAnt-Contrib/NantContrib.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0
Target(s) specified: test

  [include] C:\Code\trunk\tools\nAnt-Contrib\NantContrib.build(3,6):
  [include] Build file 'C:\Code\trunk\tools\properties.xml' does not exist.

init:


debug:

Built-in property 'nant.project.basedir' is deprecated. Use the project::get-bas
e-directory() function instead.

set-runtime-configuration:

C:\Code\trunk\tools\nAnt-Contrib\NantContrib.build(331,10): Task <ifnot> is depr
ecated.  Use the <if> task instead.
    [ifnot] C:\Code\trunk\tools\nAnt-Contrib\NantContrib.build(331,10): Attribut
e 'propertyexists' for <ifnot ... /> is deprecated.  Use <if test="${property::e
xists('propertyname')}"> instead.
C:\Code\trunk\tools\nAnt-Contrib\NantContrib.build(332,14): Task <ifnot> is depr
ecated.  Use the <if> task instead.
    [ifnot] C:\Code\trunk\tools\nAnt-Contrib\NantContrib.build(332,14): Attribut
e 'propertyexists' for <ifnot ... /> is deprecated.  Use <if test="${property::e
xists('propertyname')}"> instead.
C:\Code\trunk\tools\nAnt-Contrib\NantContrib.build(335,14): Task <ifnot> is depr
ecated.  Use the <if> task instead.
    [ifnot] C:\Code\trunk\tools\nAnt-Contrib\NantContrib.build(335,14): Attribut
e 'targetexists' for <ifnot ... /> is deprecated.  Use <if test="${target::exist
s('targetname')}"> instead.

BUILD FAILED - 1 non-fatal error(s), 7 warning(s)

C:\Code\trunk\tools\nAnt-Contrib\NantContrib.build(336,18):
No runtime configuration was specified and the current runtime (net-2.0) is not
supported by NAnt.

Total time: 0.3 seconds.
```

I am running 32bit Windows 7 OS. If I try and use the dll that is included in the zip I get the following error.

```
C:\Code\trunk\build>call ..\tools\nant\nant-0.90\bin\nant.exe /f:build-database.
xml.build
NAnt 0.90 (Build 0.90.3780.0; release; 5/8/2010)
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Gerry Shaw
http://nant.sourceforge.net

[loadtasks] Failure scanning "C:\Code\trunk\tools\nant\nant-0.90\bin\extensions\
common\2.0\CollectionGen.dll" for extensions. Could not load file or assembly 'M
icrosoft.VSDesigner, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7
f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
.
[loadtasks] Failure scanning "C:\Code\trunk\tools\nant\nant-0.90\bin\extensions\
common\2.0\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" for extensions. Unable to load one or more of
 the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more informatio
n.
Buildfile: file:///C:/Code/trunk/build/build-database.xml.build
Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0
Target(s) specified: go

 [property] Target framework changed to "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5".

go:

     [echo] Building!

BUILD SUCCEEDED

Total time: 0.1 seconds.
```

I am guessing there is a dependency missing ('Microsoft.VSDesigner') but was hoping the build script provided could shed some light on the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest versions (NAnt 0.91-alpha2 and NAntConrib 0.85).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right and the whole .Net framework installed? (I used to have **client profile** only, though it seems framework folder had all files and folders.)

Anyway, download your needed .net framework here (not only client profile):
[.NET Frameworks Microsoft Downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/search.aspx?q=.NET%20framework)